# How to add a column for descending row numbers into dataset in R

Tags: r, dataset, dplyr

I am new to R and would like to insert a new column that numbers the row to a large dataset.

I have no idea how to use `'mutate()'` to insert this. Would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mutate` in combination with `row_number` as follows:

```
df %>% mutate(row = row_number())
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked